# How do I place my widget in the top Center location using Media Query in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I have the following dial located at the center of my screen. 
I have called three different part to construct this dial.
However it seems to be stuck in the center of my screen and I want to shift it to the top center portion. Ive tried changing the alignments but it doesn't seem to work. 
[image]
This is my code:

This is the dependency I'm using: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic

```
import 'package:flutter_neumorphic/flutter_neumorphic.dart';
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                pedometerOuterDial(context),
                pedometerInnerDial(context),
                      Center(child: stepText()),
              ],
            );
          }

          Widget stepText() {
            return Text(
              '4800\nSteps',
              style: khomeStyle.copyWith(color: kOrange),
            );
          }
          Widget pedometerOuterDial(context) {
            final percentage = 30.0;
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Neumorphic(
                  boxShape: NeumorphicBoxShape.circle(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  style: NeumorphicStyle(
                    depth: NeumorphicTheme.embossDepth(context),
                  ),
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    painter: NeuProgressPainter(
                      circleWidth: 20,
                      completedPercentage: percentage,
                      defaultCircleColor: Colors.transparent,
                    ),
                    child: Center(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }

          Widget pedometerInnerDial(context) {
            return Align(
              child: Neumorphic(
                boxShape: NeumorphicBoxShape.circle(),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(80),
                style: NeumorphicStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  depth: NeumorphicTheme.depth(context),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
```

Also I haven't used Media Query here for any of the dials, so will that be an issue for displaying on other devices?

Comment: Please provide compilable code, themes are missing as well some classes

Comment: Ive edited it you can have a look

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a stack widget, the best way to do this is to use a positioned widget. You can place the widget on top by wrapping it with Positioned and setting the top property to 0.
Here is an example:

```
Positioned(
 top:0,
 child:YourWidget(),
),
```

Alignment won't work for the stack widget because it only aligns the items when there are extra space around it. Example: It works in a Column or Row since they occupy space and allow the widgets inside it to be placed and move around the occupied space.